# Retrieve History object from ModelCheckpoint in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a `ModelCheckpoint` saved on local drive. Is it somehow possible to retrieve the `History` object from this? I forgot to save this object, and now I want to plot the training graph for visualization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not, the history object is not saved in the HDF5 file, if you have checkpoint files for each epoch (depending on how you configured the `ModelCheckpoint` callback), you could get an approximation if you evaluate on your train and test sets at each epoch.